# Can I make an iPad external keyboard shortcut to delete a photo?

Tags: ipad

If I am scrolling through photos in the Photos app on the iPad, deleting them, is there an external physical keyboard shortcut with which I can delete the photo, instead of pressing on the menus?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Simply when looking at the photo, press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete a photo, however this will prompt you to confirm your deletion.

To directly delete a photo, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Ths does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

To directly delete a photo without being asked for a confirmation, use `Cmd`+`Backspace`.